# Composition factors appearing as simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I just saw the proof of the following corollary of Jordan Holder's Theorem.

> Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra. Then for every simple $A$-module $S$, $S$ appears as a composition factor in every composition series of  $A$-module $A$.

Now I am wondering the converse:

> For each composition factor $M$ in the composition series of the $A$-module $A$, must there exist a simple submodule $N$ of $A$ such that $N \cong M$?

I tried a few examples; in particular, the case for real upper triangular seems to imply the above is not true?

Comment: I am confused by the statement of your proposed converse in a few places. Firstly shouldn't "an $A$-module $A$" be "the $A$-module $A$"? Secondly you posit the existence of a simple $A$-module but don't mention it again (let's call it $N$). Thirdly by "in $A$", do you mean that $N$ should be a submodule of $A$, or just a subfactor? Finally shouldn't $A\cong M$ instead be $N\cong M$?

Comment: Yes sorry. Let me make the edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

A ring $R$ is called **right Kasch** if every simple right $R$ module is isomorphic to a minimal right ideal of $R$.

In your question, a ring with a right composition series is necessarily right Artinian, so you seek for a right Artinian ring which is not right Kasch.

[Here is the query at the Database of Ring Theory](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?has=3&lacks=53) that yields some examples, most of which *are* upper triangular matrix rings as you suspected. (And there is one that is a subring of the upper triangular matrix ring.)

Let's analyze the smallest one appearing: $R=T_2(F_2)$.

The ring has two maximal right ideals:

$M_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&F\\0&F\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$M_2=\begin{bmatrix}F&F\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

We'll call $S_1=R/M_1$ and $S_2=R/M_2$, which are all of the the simple right $R$ modules.

It only has two minimal right ideals:

$N_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&F\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$N_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&F\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, $N_1\cong N_2$ as right $R$ modules via the obvious map, and they are also isomorphic to $R/M_2$ as a right module, and so their right annihilator is $M_2$.

But the annihilator of $S_1=R/M_1$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&F\\0&F\end{bmatrix}$, so clearly $S_1$ is a simple right $R$ module that does not appear as a minimal right ideal of $R$.

But of course, you have the composition series $\{0\}\subseteq N_2\subseteq M_1\subseteq R$ whose factors exhibit both simple modules $S_1$ and $S_2$.